# Get all friend_user_id values from wp_bp_friends WHERE initiator_user_id IN ($array_of_ids)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, prepared-statement, where-in

I am making looped queries on my `wp_bp_friends` database table and returning an array of single-property objects each time.  I would like to merge all of these values into a single flat array then implode with commas.

My current code:

```
foreach ( $friendsid as $row )
{
    $sql1= "SELECT friend_user_id
            FROM wp_bp_friends
            WHERE initiator_user_id='".$row->friend_user_id."'
              AND is_confirmed = 1";
    $ffid = $wpdb->get_results($sql1);
    // $recur_multi_dimen_arr_obj =  new RecursiveArrayIterator($ffid);
    // $recur_flat_arr_obj =  new     RecursiveIteratorIterator($recur_multi_dimen_arr_obj);
    // $flat_arr = iterator_to_array($recur_flat_arr_obj, false);
    // print_r($flat_arr);
    print_r($ffid);
}
```

It outputs the following

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 62)
    [1] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 51)
    [2] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 60)
    [3] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 65)
    [4] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 56)
)
Array(
    [0] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 43)
    [1] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 50)
    [2] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 64)
    [3] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 45)
    [4] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 44)
)
Array(
    [0] => stdClassObject([friend_user_id] => 57)
)
```

Using

```
$resultarray = array();
foreach($ffid as $oneitem){
    $resultarray[]=$oneitem->friend_user_id;
} 
$excluded_user =implode(", ",$resultarray);
```

I get:

```
$excluded_user = 57;
```

What I need to end up with is

```
$excluded_user = '62, 51, 60, 65, 56, 43, 50, 64, 45, 44, 57;
```

How can I combine the arrays in $ffid before I use the foreach loop?

Note that the number of arrays in $ffid can vary.

Comment: Looks like you're reinitialising `$resultarray` in each iteration of the outer loop (`$friendsid as $row`). You need to move your initialisation of this to before this first `foreach`.

Comment: @colmde thanks, that's exactly what was needed - can't see a way to accept your answer though?

Comment: I think Kushwaha is getting at the same thing in the code he/she posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)  and [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) do the trick. A standalone code sample follows:

```
function flatten ( $item, $key, &$trg ) {
    array_push($trg, $item);
}
function hoist ( $item ) {
    return $item->friend_user_id;
}

$basearray = array(
                  array(
                      (Object)array("friend_user_id" => 62)
                    , (Object)array("friend_user_id" => 9)
                    , (Object)array("friend_user_id" => 42)
                  )
                , array(
                      (Object)array("friend_user_id" => 1)
                    , (Object)array("friend_user_id" => 2)
                    , (Object)array("friend_user_id" => 3)
                  )
                , array(
                      (Object)array("friend_user_id" => 99)
                    , (Object)array("friend_user_id" => 9)
                  )
             );
$resultarray = array();             
array_walk_recursive ( $basearray, 'flatten', &$resultarray );
print_r($resultarray);
$resultarray = array_map ( 'hoist', $resultarray );
print_r($resultarray);
$excluded_user = implode(", ",$resultarray);
print_r("excluded_user = " . $excluded_user . "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function, to create an array which includes all the data.

Something like this:

```
$arrFfid = array();
foreach ( $friendsid as $row )
{
    $sql1= "SELECT friend_user_id  FROM wp_bp_friends WHERE      initiator_user_id='".$row->friend_user_id."' AND is_confirmed = 1";
    $ffid = $wpdb->get_results($sql1);

    $arrFfid = array_merge($arrFfid, $ffid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:
Some thing like this

```
$resultarray =array();
foreach ( $friendsid as $row )
{
   $sql1= "SELECT friend_user_id  FROM wp_bp_friends WHERE initiator_user_id='".$row->friend_user_id."' AND is_confirmed = 1";
   $ffid = $wpdb->get_results($sql1);
   foreach($ffid as $oneitem){
      $resultarray[] =$oneitem->friend_user_id;
   } 
}
$excluded_user =implode(", ",$resultarray);
```

Comment: indent code by 4 characters to have it properly formatted ( monospace font, grey background ).

Answer (score 1):

[**array_map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [**array_merge**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) seems to be a good choice for this

```
$result = array();
foreach ( $friendsid as $row ) {
    ...
    ...
    $r = array_map(function($item) {
        return $item->friend_user_id;
    }, $ffid);
    $result = array_merge($result,$r);
}

$excluded_user = implode(", ", array_unique($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you should not be making multiple trips to the database for this payload of data.  You should be passing your array of friend ids to a prepared statement which contains a dynamically populated string of delimited question marks (e.g. `initiator_user_id IN (?,?,?)`).  I even have [a demonstration of how to do this with Wordpress helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68817629/2943403).

I don't use Wordpress, but I assume `get_col()` is the ideal helper method to isolate the results.

```
$friendIds = array_column($friendsid , 'friend_user_id');
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($friendIds), '%s'));
$sql = "SELECT friend_user_id
        FROM wp_bp_friends
        WHERE is_confirmed = 1
          AND initiator_user_id IN ($placeholders)";
echo implode(',', $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($sql, $friendIds)));
```