# Trying to put an array into my query mysql wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to input an array into my query. I am using Wordpress.
For security purposes, I need to use `%s`.

If I don't use `%s`, and put the `$results` directly inside the query, it works.
But if I use `%s`, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```php
<?php
/*$sym_result is an array*/

$result = implode("','",$sym_result); 
$results = "'".$result."'";

$sql = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM dis WHERE fruit IN (%s)
            ",$results));
print_r($sql);/*echo array()*/
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634058/issue-when-trying-to-use-in-in-wpdb

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM dis WHERE fruit IN ("%s", "$results")
```

It's unclear from your question if you are wanting to use "%s" in lieu of "$results" or in addition? Either way it's the inverted commas that could be the issue I reckon.

Otherwise have you tried LIKE xxx OR xxx instead of IN? I have a feeling IN doesn't allow wildcards.