# How to pass array values into prepared SQL WHERE IN statement?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Trying to pass a 2D array into a prepared WP SQL statement.

`$idList` is the 2D array.

This is what I have:

```
    $implodelist = ".implode(',', $idList).";
    
    
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT wp_users.`user_email`,
       wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic.`correct_count`,
       wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic.`incorrect_count`,
       wp_wp_pro_quiz_category.`category_name`
    FROM wp_users
      INNER JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref
         ON wp_users.`ID` = wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref.`user_id`
      INNER JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic
         ON wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref.`statistic_ref_id` = wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic.`statistic_ref_id`
      INNER JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_question
         ON wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic.`question_id` = wp_wp_pro_quiz_question.`id`
      INNER JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_category
         ON wp_wp_pro_quiz_question.`category_id` = wp_wp_pro_quiz_category.`category_id`
    WHERE wp_users.`ID` IN %s", $implodelist));
```

But the array (as a string) does not seem to be passed correctly into the %s placeholder.

If I remove the prepared statement and have `".implode(',', $idList)."` in place of `%s`, it works.

How can I pass the array values into the SQL statement?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634058/issue-when-trying-to-use-in-in-wpdb) should help.

Comment: Thank you @Jeto. I think it will help. I will have a play!