# How to fetch all data from a SELECT query as an array of associative rows in Wordpress?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, resultset, result-object

I take it from the database and send it via ajax (wordpress). Everything works fine, except that I don't get the **first row** from the database. As I read on the Internet, a similar problem is in the array, maybe. Can someone explain and help me fix it so that all rows are displayed?

Code:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM users" );

$count = 0;
$user_object = array();
foreach( $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) as $key => $row ) {
    $user_id = $row->user_ID;
    $user_name = $row->user_name;

    $user_object[$count]= array(
        "user_ID"=>$user_id,
        "user_name"=>$user_name,
    );

    $count++;
}
 
return wp_send_json( $user_object );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop your results at all, your code can be simplified further.

- There are no placeholders to bind variables to, so there is no need to use `prepare()`.
- There is no need to loop and manually set the indexes on the first level or the associative keys on the second level because `get_results()` with `ARRAY_A` will already do this for you.

Code:

```
 return wp_send_json($wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM users', ARRAY_A));
```

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

---

When you want to add PHP variables to your SQL, then using a prepared statement is appropriate.  For example: [WordPress prepared statement with IN() condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68817629/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress database tables always use prefix so you have to include prefix using `$wpdb->prefix.'users'` Or if you are trying to get WordPress core users then you can use `$wpdb->users` to get the table name with prefix.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/.

You can use `ARRAY_A` for second output parameter of `get_results()` so you don't have to loop through results.

Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/.

Code:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->users}" );
return wp_send_json($wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A));
```

Or alternative there is another way to getting users in WordPress using `get_users()`.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/

Comment: Why is `prepare()` necessary?

Comment: it is not necessary until we bind a php variable to the query.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought.  I prefer to minimize the number of method calls in my script -- especially if there is no benefit.  It looks like you could have just mentioned `{$wpdb->users}` as a comment under my answer. We have reason to believe that the asker's project isn't using table prefixes. There seems to be a significant amount of redundancy between our answers.

Comment: but i always use prepared statement in my custom queries. is it good or not?